# How to fix Unable to infer object type from error in Hubspot PHP integration

Tags: php, laravel, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I'm currently getting the same error as https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-php/issues/128, but in my case I'm using the Read endpoint. Please see my code below.

**Code**

```
$client = Factory::createWithAccessToken($accessToken);

try {
    $apiResponse = $client->crm()->companies()->basicApi()->getById('361', [
        'name', 'city', 'country', 'description', 'industry', 'external_id'
    ], false, 'external_id');

    return response()->json($apiResponse);
} catch (ApiException $e) {
    return response()->json($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Error**

> Unable to infer object type from: external_id

**Laravel version**: 9

**Hubspot API Client version**: 9.2